# c++ boost thread glibc detected invalid pointer

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, glibc

I am trying out the boost thread library with the following piece of code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/thread.hpp>

class TestSource{

private:

void workerFunc(int x){
    int p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i){
        p += 1;
    }
    std::cout<<"thread worker #"<<x<<std::endl;
}

public:

TestSource(){}

~TestSource(){}

void testFunc(){
    boost::thread_group tg;

    boost::thread t1(&TestSource::workerFunc,this,1);
    boost::thread t2(&TestSource::workerFunc,this,2);
    boost::thread t3(&TestSource::workerFunc,this,3);
    boost::thread t4(&TestSource::workerFunc,this,4);
    boost::thread t5(&TestSource::workerFunc,this,5);
    boost::thread t6(&TestSource::workerFunc,this,6);
    boost::thread t7(&TestSource::workerFunc,this,7);
    boost::thread t8(&TestSource::workerFunc,this,8);
    boost::thread t9(&TestSource::workerFunc,this,9);
    boost::thread t10(&TestSource::workerFunc,this,10);

    tg.add_thread(&t1);
    tg.add_thread(&t2);
    tg.add_thread(&t3);
    tg.add_thread(&t4);
    tg.add_thread(&t5);
    tg.add_thread(&t6);
    tg.add_thread(&t7);
    tg.add_thread(&t8);
    tg.add_thread(&t9);
    tg.add_thread(&t10);

    tg.join_all();
}

};



int main(){
TestSource ts;
ts.testFunc();
return 0;
}
```

When i run this program I **"usually"** get output of the form

```
thread worker #10
thread worker #7
thread worker #8
thread worker #6
thread worker #4
thread worker #3
thread worker #1
thread worker #9
thread worker #5
thread worker #2
```

**But, "occasionally"** I get output of the form,

```
thread worker #7
thread worker #8
thread worker #4
thread worker #2
thread worker #thread worker #5
thread worker #10
1
thread worker #6
thread worker #3
thread worker #9
*** glibc detected *** /home/aditya/workspace/testProj/all: free(): invalid pointer:   0xbff0616c ***
======= Backtrace: =========
[0x80cdd8f]
[0x80a260f]
[0x804c466]
[0x804cc8b]
[0x804a1c3]
[0x80b6266]
[0x804a089]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0818c000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 14812395   /home/aditya/workspace/testProj/all
0818c000-0818e000 rw-p 00143000 08:04 14812395   /home/aditya/workspace/testProj/all
0818e000-08198000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0a08d000-0a0af000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b2200000-b2221000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b2221000-b2300000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b2400000-b2421000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b2421000-b2500000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b2600000-b2621000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b2621000-b2700000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b2738000-b2739000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b2739000-b273a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b273a000-b2f3a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b2f3a000-b2f3b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0  
b2f3b000-b373b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b373b000-b373c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b373c000-b3f3c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b3f3c000-b3f3d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b3f3d000-b473d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7742000-b7743000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7743000-b7744000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
bfee6000-bff07000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

I am not sure why this occasional behaviour is manifesting. Appreciate any help to understand what's exactly happening.

Thanks for responses,

Comment: How are you compiling the code? What operating system are you using?

Comment: You're getting some weirdness in your output as you're not protecting your accesses to `std::cout`. But I don't think thats your invalid free issus.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson  i'm compiling it with g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/boost_1_50_0 main.cpp -o all -static -L/usr/local/boost_1_50_0/stage/lib -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread. i'm using ubuntu 12.04. just to clarify, i compile once but independent runs of the program toggle between the error free and error version of output..

Comment: You probably want to compile with `-pthread` rather than `-lpthread`, (that used to matter in older versions of g++, unsure about recent versions). You might want to enable debug information, so your backtraces look better, with `-g`.

Comment: Also its probably worth running your application through valgrind and helgrind to see if that spots anything.

Comment: Just tested your code and for me it crashes every time (also when I remove the suspect std::cout line). Boost 1.48 gcc 4.7.0. Valgrind points to boost::thread_group::~thread_group() (thread_group.hpp:34) for being the culprit.

Comment: @Eelke thank you for debugging it. hmm, so does that cast question on the boost thread_group suite ? or is there something wrong in the way i'm using the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look at the thread_group header told me the folowing. boost::thread_group expects you to pass a pointer to an object allocated with new to the add_thread function as it will try to delete them in the destructor.

The boost documentation lists the following precodintion for the [add_thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.threadgroup.add_thread) method:

> The expression delete thrd is well-formed and will not result in
>   undefined behaviour.

Where thrd is the parameter to the add_thread method.